# Pygame project i'm stuck, please reply

Tags: python, windows, eclipse, drawing, pygame

So i'm using python 2.7.3 and 1.9.1 or 1.9.2, and i'm making a little app where you can draw and change colors and save. there's only one big problem. i'll show you the code first(full code)

```
    import sys, pygame
from pygame import *

pygame.init()

size = 500, 500

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

screen.fill((255,255,255))

brush = pygame.image.load("C:\Users\Pygame draw\\black1.png")

pygame.display.set_caption("THE EPIC DRAWING THING...")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

black = pygame.image.load("C:\Users\Pygame draw\\black.png")
white = pygame.image.load("C:\Users\Pygame draw\white.png")
blue = pygame.image.load("C:\Users\Pygame draw\\blue.png")
brown = pygame.image.load("C:\Users\Pygame draw\\brown.png")
green = pygame.image.load("C:\Users\Pygame draw\green.png")
light_blue = pygame.image.load("C:\Users\Pygame draw\light blue.png")
pink = pygame.image.load("C:\Users\Pygame draw\pink.png")
purple =pygame.image.load("C:\Users\Pygame draw\purple.png") 
red = pygame.image.load("C:\Users\Pygame draw\\red.png")
save = pygame.image.load("C:\Users\Pygame draw\save drawing.png")
exit = pygame.image.load("C:\Users\Pygame draw\exit.png")
black1 = pygame.image.load("C:\Users2\Pygame draw\\black1.png")
white1 = pygame.image.load("C:\Users\Pygame draw\white1.png")
blue1 = pygame.image.load("C:\Users\Pygame draw\\blue1.png")
brown1 = pygame.image.load("C:\Users\Pygame draw\\brown1.png")
green1 = pygame.image.load("C:\Users\Pygame draw\green1.png")
light_blue1 = pygame.image.load("C:\Users\Pygame draw\light blue1.png")
pink1 = pygame.image.load("C:\Users\Pygame draw\pink1.png")
purple1 =pygame.image.load("C:\Users\Pygame draw\purple1.png") 
red1 = pygame.image.load("C:\Users\Pygame draw\\red1.png")

z = 0

while 1:
    clock.tick(60)
    mx,my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:sys.exit()
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:sys.exit()
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and pygame.mouse.get_pressed(): z = 1
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP: z = 0
        if z == 1:
            screen.blit(brush,(mx-5,my-5))


    screen.blit(black,(0,0))
    screen.blit(brown,(21,0))
    screen.blit(purple,(42,0))
    screen.blit(blue,(63,0))
    screen.blit(light_blue,(84,0))
    screen.blit(green,(105,0))
    screen.blit(red,(126,0))
    screen.blit(pink,(148,0))
    screen.blit(white,(169,0))
    screen.blit(save,(207,0))
    screen.blit(exit,(430,0))
    pygame.display.update()
```

So basically, i want it to be so that if i, let's say, click the picture "red", brush turns into "red1" that's the only thing i need help with, i can change the brush colour, but i just need it to be so that if i click one of them, i can change the brush colour
Thanks :)
p.s i use eclipse as the IDE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out:

```
import os.path

img_dir = "C:/Users/Pygame draw/" 

image_files = [
    'black.png',
    'white.png',
    'blue.png',
]

py_images = {}

for image_file in image_files:
    color_name, ext = os.path.splitext(image_file)

    py_image = pygame.image.load(
        os.path.join(img_dir, image_file)
    )

    py_images[color_name] = py_image

points = {
    'blue' : (63, 0),
    'white' : (169, 0),
    'black' : (0, 0)
}

for color_name, point in points.items():
    py_image = py_images[color_name]
    screen.blit(py_image, point)
```

Computers are good at repetitive tasks.  If you find yourself writing the same line of code over and over again, you can use a loop instead.

As for getting the image that was clicked, you can do something like this:

```
py_rects = {}
alt_img_name = "1.png"

for color_name, point in points.items():
    py_image = py_images[color_name]

    rect = screen.blit(py_image, point)
    py_rects[rect] = color_name  

...
...


elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    mx,my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    for rect in py_rects:
        if rect.colllidepoint(mx, my):
            clicked_color_name = py_rects[rect]
            point = points[clicked_color_name]
            py_image = pygame.image.load(
                os.path.join(img_dir, clicked_color_name + alt_img_name)
            )

            screen.blit(py_image, point)
            break
```

And so that you don't have to re-create the new py_image if you've already done it before, you can do something like this:

```
    for rect in py_rects:
        if rect.colllidepoint(mx, my):
            clicked_color_name = py_rects[rect]
            point = points[clicked_color_name]
            py_image = py_images.setdefault(
                clicked_color_name + "1",
                pygame.image.load(
                    os.path.join(img_dir, clicked_color_name + alt_img_name)
                )

            screen.blit(py_image, point)
            break
```

Comment: where about in the code do i put the image was clicked thing? also, i'm kinda used to doing the way i do it now, i find it easier and i understand it now, but thanks :)

Comment: You will have to someone how construct the new image name from the image that was clicked.  I'm not sure how you would do that without associating the rect that was clicked with an image name, i.e. using a dictionary.  As for where the code goes, the `elif event.type == MOUSEDOWN:` should nail that down.